# How to compare dates in alasql in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, alasql

I am having trouble trying to compare dates in my AlaSql query in Google Scripts. I tried different codes. But no one work. 
I have one google spreadsheet and I need to get query from it. I want to filter by Col15 with dates. Dates in spreadsheets look like

```
01.02.2019
```

and format like

```
Fri Feb 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
```

so i tried different sql querys:

```
var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Col15 from ?  where Col15 "+ date_left +"  BETWEEN AND "+ date_right +" "; 

  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Col15 from ?  where   DATE(Col15) > CURRENT_DATE() "; 
  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Col15 from ?  where  ( Col15 > "+ date_left + ")) "; 
  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Col15 from ?  where  ( DATE(Col15) > DATE('20-07-2018')) "; 
  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Col15 from ?  where  ( YEAR(Col15) > YEAR('20.07.2018')) ";   
  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Col15 from ?  where (Col15 <> '') or ( YEAR(Col15) > YEAR('20.07.2018')) ";   
  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Col15 from ?  where (Col15 <> '') or (DATE(Col15) BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2019/01/01')  ";
  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Date(Col15) from ?  where  ( Col15 > Date '27/07/2019' )  ";
  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Date(Col15) from ?  where  ( Col15 > Date '27-07-2019' )  ";
  //var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Date(Col15) from ?  where  ( Col15 > Date '27.07.2019' )  ";

var data = getAlaSql(sql, data_sheet);
```

in all cases result null. 
I read a lot of sites about SQL. But nothing work. I am crazy about it.

There are some error

```
Error: Parse error on line 1: ...] from ? where Col 15 31-01-2019 BETWE 
-----------------------^ Expecting 'IN', 'LIKE', 'ARROW', 'DOT', 'CARET',
 'EQ', 'SLASH', 'EXCLAMATION', 'MODULO', 'GT', 'LT', 'GTGT', 'LTLT', 'NOT',
 'AND', 'OR', 'PLUS', 'STAR', 'REGEXP', 'GLOB', 'NOT_LIKE', 'BARBAR', 'MINUS',
 'AMPERSAND', 'BAR', 'GE', 'LE', 'EQEQ', 'EQEQEQ', 'NE', 'NEEQEQ', 'NEEQEQEQ',
 'BETWEEN', 'NOT_BETWEEN', 'IS', 'DOUBLECOLON', 'GO', 'SEMICOLON', 'ELSE', 
'END', 'OFFSET', 'LIMIT', 'GROUP', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT', 'UNION', 'ORDER', 
'RPAR', 'WITH', 'EOF', got 'NUMBER' (строка 8, файл #AlaSql)
```

As far as I can see AlaSql doesn't understend what I wrote.

Please help me with it.

Comment: Try using valueOf().

Comment: @Cooper thank you for info. i tried this, but it does not work ```var x1 = new Date(2019, 01, 01);
  var x2 = new Date(2019, 09, 12);
  var date_left = Utilities.formatDate( x1, "GMT" , "dd-MM-yyyy");
  var date_right = Utilities.formatDate( x2, "GMT" , "dd-MM-yyyy");
  Logger.log("x1 = " + x1);
  Logger.log("date_left = " + date_left);
  
  
  var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, Col15 from ?  where Col 15 BETWEEN "+ date_left.valueOf() +"   AND "+ date_right.valueOf() +" "; ```

Comment: I’m not sure that this will work but in your example above date_left and date_right are strings not dates.